# quit mainloop in python

Tags: python, tkinter

Although I am a kind of experimented programmer in other languages, I am very new in Python. I have been trying to do a very simple thing that is to quit the mainloop after starting. It seems that it is a big deal. The program below only makes a sequence of events. Everything seems to be working, but I am not able to close the final window... What should I do?

```
from Tkinter import *

root=Tk()
theMainFrame=Frame(root)
theMainFrame.pack()



class CloseAfterFinishFrame1(Frame): # Diz que herda os parametros de Frame
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self,theMainFrame) # Inicializa com os parametros acima!!
        Label(self,text="Hi",font=("Arial", 16)).pack()
        button = Button (self, text = "I am ready", command=self.CloseWindow,font=("Arial", 12))
        button.pack()            
        self.pack()

    def CloseWindow(self):
        self.forget()
        CloseAfterFinishFrame2()



class CloseAfterFinishFrame2(Frame): # Diz que herda os parametros de Frame
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self,theMainFrame) # Inicializa com os parametros acima!!
        Label(self,text="Hey",font=("Arial", 16)).pack()
        button = Button (self, text = "the End", command=self.CloseWindow,font=("Arial", 12))
        button.pack()
        self.pack()        
    def CloseWindow(self):
        self.forget()
        CloseEnd()


class CloseEnd():
    theMainFrame.quit()



CloseAfterFinishFrame1()

theMainFrame.mainloop()
```

Comment: you can use `root .withdraw()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call `root.quit()`, not `theMainFrame.quit`:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class CloseAfterFinishFrame1(tk.Frame):  # Diz que herda os parametros de Frame
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)  # Inicializa com os parametros acima!!
        tk.Label(self, text="Hi", font=("Arial", 16)).pack()
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="I am ready",
                           command=self.CloseWindow, font=("Arial", 12))
        self.button.pack()
        self.pack()

    def CloseWindow(self):
        # disable the button so pressing <SPACE> does not call CloseWindow again
        self.button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.forget()
        CloseAfterFinishFrame2(self.master)

class CloseAfterFinishFrame2(tk.Frame):  # Diz que herda os parametros de Frame
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)  # Inicializa com os parametros acima!!
        tk.Label(self, text="Hey", font=("Arial", 16)).pack()
        button = tk.Button(self, text="the End",
                           command=self.CloseWindow, font=("Arial", 12))
        button.pack()
        self.pack()

    def CloseWindow(self):
        root.quit()

root = tk.Tk()
CloseAfterFinishFrame1(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Also, there is no need to make a class `CloseEnd` if all you want to do is call the function `root.quit`.

Comment: Thank you! But after pressing the Button theEnd, program becomes stuck! I am using python 2.7.3! By the way, what is the advantage of defining Tkinter as tk? I saw other people also doing that, but I didnt understand the reason!

Comment: Are you using an IDE? If so, try running the script from the command line: `python script.py`. I think it should work fine.

Comment: Although some might argue that `import * from Tkinter` is okay -- indeed, I think the author of `Tkinter` designed it to be imported that way -- *in general* one should only use `import * ...` in interactive sessions, not in scripts. By using the more verbose `import Tkinter as tk`, you clarify exactly where every object is coming from. That helps when debugging or reading other people's code, and it prevents name collisions when two modules use the same names. For example, `numpy.sum` is different than the builtin Python `sum`. `import * from numpy` would be awful.

Comment: You are right. I was using the idle. It works now! I really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

you can use root.destroy()
i seem it's working on my last programme,i hope it's useful for you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).