# Closing the window doesn't kill all processes

Tags: python, tkinter, osx-yosemite

I have a very simple programme that displays a simple plot on press of a button. My problem is when I close the application window, the programme keeps running until I kill it from the terminal. Below is my code and my investigation showed the issue is caused by

```
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

But I don't know how to fix it! If it helps, I'm running on OSX.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Tkinter import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# ------ End of imports

class Ops:
    def show_plot(self):
        self.f, self.figarray = plt.subplots(1, sharex=True, sharey=True)
        self.figarray.plot((1,2,3),(1,2,3))
        plt.tight_layout()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, master=self.mainFrame)
        self.canvas._tkcanvas.config(background='white', borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)


class GUI(Ops):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.width = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()  # Width of the screen
        self.height = self.master.winfo_screenheight()  # Height of the screen
        self.x = (self.width / 2)
        self.y = (self.height / 2)
        self.master.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (self.width, self.height, self.x, self.y))
        self.mainFrame = Frame(self.master)  # Generate the main container
        self.mainFrame.pack()

        # ---------- TOP FRAME ----------
        self.topFrame = Frame(self.mainFrame)
        self.topFrame.pack()

        self.browse_button = Button(self.topFrame, text="Plot", command=self.show_plot)
        self.browse_button.grid()


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.file_handler = Ops()
        self.root = Tk()
        self.gui_handler = GUI(self.root)

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop() 

Application = App()
Application.run()
```

Comment: The code above is correct; there must be something else which prevents the process from stopping. Do you create child processes or daemon threads?

Comment: @AaronDigulla The problem arises when the data is plotted. Otherwise it exits fine. I have now added the whole code with dummy data so it can be reproduced.

Comment: Does it hang when you exit while the data is plotted? Does it hang, after the plotting has finished?

Comment: @AaronDigulla It hangs when I close the window after the data is plotted.

Comment: Is that really already a minimal example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `root.quit()` to end the Tk.mainloop(). For example, see the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838635/quit-mainloop-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple. Just use

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
```

instead of

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `root.mainloop` outside of a function, that should solve your problems.