# Python GUI Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

I want to have a function run continuously within a tkinter GUI. I have attached some shell code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep
import os
import sys

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

        def create_widgets(self):
        ......

root = Tk()  

def run_continously:
    ... -- calls sleep -- ...
    root.after(3000, run_continuously)


root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
app = Application(root)
root.after(3000, run_continuously)          
root.mainloop()
```

When running the GUI it tends to run the 'run_continuously' function once and the GUI freezes up. I suspect from poking around that this is due to the sleep function (which I call in the run_continuously function)

How would I go about implementing the 'run_continuously' function in a very simple thread to get around this issue? Would running the function in a thread even get me around the problem? The 'run_continuously' function does not need to interact at all with the Application class. I want it to run simply in the background and stop when the mainloop is finished.

Here is the end of the code:

```
def run_continuously(quit_flag):
    print("in it")
    if not quit_flag:
        GPIO.output(DIR_PIN, True)
        for i in range(steps):
            print("in loop")
            GPIO.output(STEP_PIN, True)
            sleep(sDelay)
            GPIO.output(STEP_PIN, False)
            sleep(sDelay)
        sleep(wait_time)
        GPIO.output(DIR_PIN, False)    
        for i in range(steps):
            GPIO.output(STEP_PIN, True)
            sleep(sDelay)
            GPIO.output(STEP_PIN, False)
            sleep(sDelay)
            print("run motor")
        root.after(1000, run_continuously(quit_flag,))


#=================================================================
# main
#=================================================================

root = Tk()                            # Create the GUI root object
press1 = StringVar()
press2 = StringVar()

x = 275
y = 50
w = 580
h = 250


root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
app = Application(root)          # Create the root application window
quit_flag = False                
root.after(0, app.read_pressure)
motor_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_continuously, args=(quit_flag,)).start()
root.mainloop()
quit_flag=True
motor_thread.join()
```

Comment: Why are you calling sleep in `run_continuously`? What purpose does that serve?

Comment: Why don't you try `import threading` and create a `threading.Thread` to run `run_continuously`?

Comment: the run continuously function outputs values to control a stepper motor. It uses the sleep function, but not exclusively.

Comment: David - I tried that and the run_continuously function only executed once:

Comment: `root.after` is the tk equivalent of `time.sleep`.  In the tk thread, do not use `sleep`.  Since your code is not an MCVE, https://www.google.com/search?q=mcve&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8, it is impossible to experiment with you code to be sure of what is wrong.  If you need pauses within `run_continuously`, then you may need to break it up into subfunctions to use root.after for the pausing.

Comment: I have to use sleep because root.after will not allow time intervals less than 1 sec (it only accepts integers), my step motor take ms steps otherwise it will take too long using .after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exits cleanly if the 'QUIT' button is pressed or Ctrl-C is pressed:

```
from Tkinter import *
import multiprocessing
import threading
import time
import logging


class Application(Frame):
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.quit_button = Button(self)
        self.quit_button['text'] = 'QUIT'
        self.quit_button['fg'] = 'red'
        self.quit_button['command'] = self.quit
        self.quit_button.pack({'side': 'left'})

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.quit_button = None
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.poll()

    def poll(self):
        """
        This method is required to allow the mainloop to receive keyboard
        interrupts when the frame does not have the focus
        """
        self.master.after(250, self.poll)


def worker_function(quit_flag):
    counter = 0
    while not quit_flag.value:
        counter += 1
        logging.info("Work # %d" % counter)
        time.sleep(1.0)


format = '%(levelname)s: %(filename)s: %(lineno)d: %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=format)
root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
quit_flag = multiprocessing.Value('i', int(False))
worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=worker_function, args=(quit_flag,))
worker_thread.start()
logging.info("quit_flag.value = %s" % bool(quit_flag.value))
try:
    app.mainloop()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    logging.info("Keyboard interrupt")
quit_flag.value = True
logging.info("quit_flag.value = %s" % bool(quit_flag.value))
worker_thread.join()
```

Comment: Hi David, This worked well for the most part. I added .start() after the motor_thread declaration. Running the program it works fine, but after quitting I am getting the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mDS_v14.py", line 509, in <module>
    motor_thread.join()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'join'

-----See the updated code above as well.

Comment: @RickySpanish: Review the changes in my answer. When you call `start()` in a chain, it returns `None`, so you lose your thread handle. Separate the calls as shown above to keep the thread handle. Use a `while` loop in `run_continuously` and use `time.sleep` instead of `root.after`.

Comment: Ok this works well, but now the motor_thread won't stop after I quit the GUI. After the user presses a QUIT button I call root.destroy() however the motor continues to run. after quitting the mainloop the quit_flag stays false

Comment: @RickySpanish: I think you want to call `root.quit()` per this [StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838635/quit-mainloop-in-python). My guess is that `root.destroy()` prevents any code after `root.mainloop()` from running.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too: after I call root.quit() the GUI freezes (doesn't quit) and the motor continues to run

The only way I can get the motor to stop from running is to do a GPIO cleanup (GPIO pins controlling the step motor)

Comment: What happens if you put `print "quit_flag = %s" % quit_flag` before and after `quit_flag = True`?

Comment: Heres what I get:

{Entering Loop1
Entering Loop2
False
True
Entering Loop1
Entering Loop2
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
File "mDS_v14.py", Line 517, in <module>
    motor_thread.join()
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/threading.py", line 854, in join
    self._block.wait()
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/threading.py", line 235, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
Entering Loop1
^CException KeyboardInterrupt: KeyboardInterrupt() in <module 'threading' from /usr/lib/python3.2/threading.py'> ignored}

Comment: @RickySpanish: I changed the code above to use a `multiprocessing.Value`. My experiments show that this survives the call to `root.mainloop()` and the program exits cleanly after `root.quit()` is called.