# Get my mainloop to exit once a condition is met Python 3.x Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a Tic Tac Toe game in tkinter that shows a grid which uses images as the "empty", "X" and "O". I used radio buttons as images with indicatoron set to 0.

I also have a list called board with 9 empty spaces. When you click on one of the empty tiles it changes to the picture to the X or O according to which turn it is and then adds either an X or O to the board list in the appropriate position. Right now,

I am trying to exit the mainloop when the condition is met that a row or column or diagonal has an X or O in all three. I have functions for these conditions and have it return True whenever a condition is met. I would like to have my mainloop exit when one of the two wins and maybe even have a pop-up that reads X Wins! or O wins!

I'm open to suggestions for a different method for determining the winner but my main concern is just getting it to stop once one of the conditions is met.

```
from tkinter import *


class TicTacToe():

    def __init__(self):

        window = Tk()
        window.title("Tic-Tac-Toe")

        self.emptyBox = PhotoImage(file = "image/empty.gif")
        self.xBox = PhotoImage(file = "image/x.gif")
        self.oBox = PhotoImage(file = "image/o.gif")  
        self.turn = 0
        self.board = [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
        self.token = IntVar()

        frame1 = Frame(window, height = 150, width = 150)
        frame1.pack()        

        self.label1 = Radiobutton(frame1, image = self.emptyBox, variable = self.token, value = 1, indicatoron = 0, command = self.addImage)
        self.label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.label2 = Radiobutton(frame1, image = self.emptyBox, variable = self.token, value = 2, indicatoron = 0, command = self.addImage)
        self.label2.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.label3 = Radiobutton(frame1, image = self.emptyBox, variable = self.token, value = 3, indicatoron = 0, command = self.addImage)
        self.label3.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

        self.label4 = Radiobutton(frame1, image = self.emptyBox, variable = self.token, value = 4, indicatoron = 0, command = self.addImage)
        self.label4.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.label5 = Radiobutton(frame1, image = self.emptyBox, variable = self.token, value = 5, indicatoron = 0, command = self.addImage)
        self.label5.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.label6 = Radiobutton(frame1, image = self.emptyBox, variable = self.token, value = 6, indicatoron = 0, command = self.addImage)
        self.label6.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        self.label7 = Radiobutton(frame1, image = self.emptyBox, variable = self.token, value = 7, indicatoron = 0, command = self.addImage)
        self.label7.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        self.label8 = Radiobutton(frame1, image = self.emptyBox, variable = self.token, value = 8, indicatoron = 0, command = self.addImage)
        self.label8.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        self.label9 = Radiobutton(frame1, image = self.emptyBox, variable = self.token, value = 9, indicatoron = 0, command = self.addImage)
        self.label9.grid(row = 2, column = 2)          

        window.mainloop()



    def doesWinX(self):
        #check if X wins
        if self.board[0] == 'X' and self.board[1] == 'X' and self.board[2] == 'X':
            return True
        elif self.board[3] == 'X' and self.board[4] == 'X' and self.board[5] == 'X':
            return True
        elif self.board[6] == 'X' and self.board[7] == 'X' and self.board[8] == 'X':
            return True 

        elif self.board[0] == 'X' and self.board[3] == 'X' and self.board[6] == 'X':
            return True
        elif self.board[1] == 'X' and self.board[4] == 'X' and self.board[7] == 'X':
            return True
        elif self.board[2] == 'X' and self.board[5] == 'X' and self.board[8] == 'X':
            return True     

        elif self.board[0] == 'X' and self.board[4] == 'X' and self.board[8] == 'X':
            return True
        elif self.board[2] == 'X' and self.board[4] == 'X' and self.board[6] == 'X':
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def doesWinO(self):
        if self.board[0] == 'O' and self.board[1] == 'O' and self.board[2] == 'O':
            return True
        elif self.board[3] == 'O' and self.board[4] == 'O' and self.board[5] == 'O':
            return True
        elif self.board[6] == 'O' and self.board[7] == 'O' and self.board[8] == 'O':
            return True 

        elif self.board[0] == 'O' and self.board[3] == 'O' and self.board[6] == 'O':
            return True
        elif self.board[1] == 'O' and self.board[4] == 'O' and self.board[7] == 'O':
            return True
        elif self.board[2] == 'O' and self.board[5] == 'O' and self.board[8] == 'O':
            return True     

        elif self.board[0] == 'O' and self.board[4] == 'O' and self.board[8] == 'O':
            return True
        elif self.board[2] == 'O' and self.board[4] == 'O' and self.board[6] == 'O':
            return True  
        else:
            return False

    def addImage(self):
        token = self.token.get()
        while self.turn % 2 == 0:
            if token == 1 and self.board[0] == ' ':
                self.label1.config(image = self.xBox)
                self.board.pop(0)
                self.board.insert(0, 'X')
                self.turn += 1
                break
            elif token == 2 and self.board[1] == ' ':
                self.label2.config(image = self.xBox)
                self.board.pop(1)
                self.board.insert(1, 'X')
                self.turn += 1
                break
            elif token == 3 and self.board[2] == ' ':
                self.label3.config(image = self.xBox)
                self.board.pop(2)
                self.board.insert(2, 'X') 
                self.turn += 1
                break
            elif token == 4 and self.board[3] == ' ':
                self.label4.config(image = self.xBox)
                self.board.pop(3)
                self.board.insert(3, 'X') 
                self.turn += 1
                break
            elif token == 5 and self.board[4] == ' ':
                self.label5.config(image = self.xBox)
                self.board.pop(4)
                self.board.insert(4, 'X')
                self.turn += 1

            elif token == 6 and self.board[5] == ' ':
                self.label6.config(image = self.xBox)
                self.board.pop(5)
                self.board.insert(5, 'X')  
                self.turn += 1
            elif token == 7 and self.board[6] == ' ':
                self.label7.config(image = self.xBox)
                self.board.pop(6)
                self.board.insert(6, 'X') 
                self.turn += 1
            elif token == 8 and self.board[7] == ' ':
                self.label8.config(image = self.xBox)
                self.board.pop(7)
                self.board.insert(7, 'X')
                self.turn += 1
            elif token == 9 and self.board[8] == ' ':
                self.label9.config(image = self.xBox)
                self.board.pop(8)
                self.board.insert(8, 'X')  
                self.turn += 1
            break

        while self.turn % 2 == 1:
            token = self.token.get()
            if token == 1 and self.board[0] == ' ':
                self.label1.config(image = self.oBox)
                self.board.pop(0)
                self.board.insert(0, 'O')
                self.turn += 1
            elif token == 2 and self.board[1] == ' ':
                self.label2.config(image = self.oBox)
                self.board.pop(1)
                self.board.insert(1, 'O')
                self.turn += 1
            elif token == 3 and self.board[2] == ' ':
                self.label3.config(image = self.oBox)
                self.board.pop(2)
                self.board.insert(2, 'O') 
                self.turn += 1
            elif token == 4 and self.board[3] == ' ':
                self.label4.config(image = self.oBox)
                self.board.pop(3)
                self.board.insert(3, 'O') 
                self.turn += 1
            elif token == 5 and self.board[4] == ' ':
                self.label5.config(image = self.oBox)
                self.board.pop(4)
                self.board.insert(4, 'O')
                self.turn += 1
            elif token == 6 and self.board[5] == ' ':
                self.label6.config(image = self.oBox)
                self.board.pop(5)
                self.board.insert(5, 'O')  
                self.turn += 1
            elif token == 7 and self.board[6] == ' ':
                self.label7.config(image = self.oBox)
                self.board.pop(6)
                self.board.insert(6, 'O')
                self.turn += 1
                break
            elif token == 8 and self.board[7] == ' ':
                self.label8.config(image = self.oBox)
                self.board.pop(7)
                self.board.insert(7, 'O')
                self.turn += 1
            elif token == 9 and self.board[8] == ' ':
                self.label9.config(image = self.oBox)
                self.board.pop(8)
                self.board.insert(8, 'O')  
                self.turn += 1
            break

TicTacToe()
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does `window.quit()` do what you're looking for. I got that from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838635/quit-mainloop-in-python

Comment: You just need to call your `doesWinX` and `doesWinO` functions after each player's turn, respectively.  Then perform an act based on the return value: `if self.doesWinX(): print("X WINS!"), window.quit()` or whatever you'd like to do

Comment: I have this but I don't think my board list is being evaluated after each turn because it didn't quit.

Answer (score 0):

Add a conditional as the very last *statement* of `addImage`

```
def addImage(self):
    .....
    .....
    if self.doesWinX() or self.doesWinO():
           print('game over!!')
```

---

To get it to close, create an instance attribute that refers to the *window*.

```
def __init__(self):

    window = Tk()
    window.title("Tic-Tac-Toe")
    # window instance attribute
    self.window = window
    ...
```

Then destroy it in the conditional that was added to `addImage`

```
    if self.doesWinX() or self.doesWinO():
        print('game over!!')
        self.window.destroy()
```

This seems a bit kludgey, I've only written a couple of tkinter apps and can't remember how I kept a reference to the Tk instance.  Maybe someone will edit this answer to make it clearer.

Comment: this doesn't cause `mainloop` to exit.